# Simple C Array Structures

Tags: c

I've been trying to tweak this problem from my textbook that explains arrays of structures.
My output was correct, but when I added another 'person' to my structure, and tried to print the result (in the 2nd print statement in displayStats()), it outputs 4 lines instead of 2.  Running this code, the output is:

> ```
> Hoover, Adam: 10.400000 PPG in 2005
> , : 0.000000 PPG in 0
> .N=ö, Ðè/: 0.000000 PPG in 1
> Jane, Mary: 10.400000 PPG in 2005
> ```

This is kind of interesting because even when I comment out the second print statement (which prints the Mary Jane line), the output is still 2 lines -- Hoover, Adam being line 1, and , : 0.00000 being line 2.  When I make all 4 fields in the array [32], I still get 4 lines of output, but the middle 2 lines are changed a bit.

I'm probably missing something really simple, but the goal is just to have 2 lines of output with Hoover, Adam and Jane, Mary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct person { /* "person" is name for structure type */
  char first[32]; /* first field of structure is array of char */
  char last[32]; /* second field is array of char */
  int year; /* third field is int */
  double ppg; /* fourth field is double */

  char second[31];
  char third[31];
  int year1;
  double ppo;
}; /* ending ; means end of structure type definition */


displayStats(struct person  Input) {
      printf("%s, %s: %lf PPG in %d\n", Input.last, Input.first, Input.ppg, Input.year);
      printf("%s, %s: %lf PPG in %d\n", Input.third, Input.second, Input.ppo, Input.year1);
   }

 int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
  struct person  teacher;
  struct person  another;

  teacher.year=2005;
  teacher.ppg=10.4;
  strcpy(teacher.first,"Adam");
  strcpy(teacher.last,"Hoover");
  displayStats(teacher);

  another.year1=2005;
  another.ppo=10.4;
  strcpy(another.second,"Mary");
  strcpy(another.third,"Jane");
  displayStats(another);

  return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing garbage because for teacher, `second` and `third` aren't assigned, and for another, `first` and `last` aren't assigned?

Why do you have `second` and `third` fields? Remove them, use `first` and `last` for both, and remove the second line in `displayStats`, and it should work.

Comment: Wouldn't changing [second and third] to [first and last] overwrite the Hoover, Adam line?

Comment: No. `teacher` and `another` are in different parts of memory, so their first and last members are also different.

Answer (score 1):

Each call to displayStats is printing two lines.  Calling it twice prints four lines.  Remove the second printf from displayStats and it should work.

Comment: The thing is, each displayStat() call should only be printing one line. When I remove the second printf statement, I get the first and third lines from above.

Comment: Change the part where you're setting `another`'s values to `first`, `last`, `year`, and `ppg`, instead of `second`,`third`,`year1` and `ppo`.

Comment: (near the end of main(), just before the return call)

Answer (score 1):

You have unnecessary fields in your struct and you are calling `printf` twice in your display function. Remove these fields:

```
struct person { /* "person" is name for structure type */
  char first[32]; /* first field of structure is array of char */
  char last[32]; /* second field is array of char */
  int year; /* third field is int */
  double ppg; /* fourth field is double */

  char second[31]; // <- Remove
  char third[31]; // <- Remove
  int year1; // <- Remove
  double ppo; // <- Remove
};
```

And change your display function to:

```
void displayStats(struct person  Input) {
      printf("%s, %s: %lf PPG in %d\n", Input.last, Input.first, Input.ppg, Input.year);
}
```